# what is the purpose of inserting a dot or a period in the id of an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i cant know what is the purpose of inserting a dot or a period in the id of an html element, is there any extra benefit we get in any coding language ?

```
<div id="PAT.TID" class="lineHeight frmData">Headset,  e.g. Bluetooth headset,  for mobile device has configuration logic which configures headset based on sensor data indicating whether headset is being worn by user</div>
```

i want to select the div of id="PAT.TID", how i can do that

```
document.querySelector('#PAT\.TID')
```

here i got a `null` object in chrome browser console

how i select like wildchar contain in id elements using pure javascript ? (like querySelector)

Comment: No, there's benefit for doing it. The only purpose it serves is to make things more difficult (as you can see!).

Comment: While it seems minitech has answered your question, I'm curious as to why you're using a dot in the first place. Was it a poor design decision from long ago, or perhaps driven by a piece of software you're currently using?

Comment: i don't do it, i saw it in thomson innovation patent search product

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JavaScript, the string literal `'#PAT\.TID'` is equivalent to `'#PAT.TID'`. You need to escape once for JavaScript, once for CSS:

```
document.querySelector('#PAT\\.TID')
```

And no, there’s no point in doing this except to make life miserable for other people.

Comment: Have a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7pc2w0yg/), was just verifying my own thoughts.

Comment: +1 @minitech. Could also mention that all `metacharacters` that have to be escaped in a selector are listed here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

There is no general technical benefit from using a period in an `id` attribute value. An `id` attribute is simply an assigned identifier, where no character has any special meaning or effect as such (except that spaces are disallowed).

A period has always been allowed, though.

The reasons why some page or site uses a period in an identifier could be found out only by investigating its internal structure and logic and its interaction with other software and possibly the minds of its designers and coders.

It is unlikely that this is an interface thing (i.e. a necessity to use the same identifier as in some existing software that is taken as given), since `id` attributes are normally internal to a page. However, it is possible that the identifiers have been copied from some external data as such, without considering the implications.

It is also possible that `id="PAT.ID"` is just one way of avoiding the restriction that an `id` attribute value cannot contain spaces. So maybe they wanted to write `"PAT ID"`, realized that it is not valid, and chose `"PAT.ID"` rather than `"PAT_ID"` or `"PAT-ID"`.

The other question (which is not reflected in the question title) was properly addressed in @minitech’s answer.